# Configure Azure WebJobs for Staging and Production

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a web application (ASP.NET MVC 4) hosted as an Azure Web Site.  It has two other components, a Worker Role and a Web Job.

The worker role does some *sniffing* into the data / activity going on in the application and queues up work for the Web Job through Azure Storage Queues, based on what I believe to be a standard pattern.  Code snippet below:

```
public class Functions
{
    // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
    // on an Azure Queue called queue.
    public static void NewBidsQueue([QueueTrigger("bids")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void SendText([QueueTrigger("texts")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void AuctionEvents([QueueTrigger("auction-events")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Since the queues are part of the function definition, is there another way to toggle the queue name in the queue-trigger besides having separate storage accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've devised a bit of a hacky work-around.  I'm using preprocessor directives to swap out string constants:

```
public static class WebJobStorageQueueNames 
{
#if DEBUG
    public const string AuctionEvents = "auction-events-test";
    public const string Texts = "texts-test";
    public const string Bids = "bids-test";
#else
    public const string AuctionEvents = "auction-events";
    public const string Texts = "texts";
    public const string Bids = "bids";
#endif
}
```

and the accompanying function definitions:

```
public class Functions 
{
    public static void NewBidsQueue([QueueTrigger(WebJobStorageQueueNames.Bids)] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void SendText([QueueTrigger(WebJobStorageQueueNames.Texts)] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void AuctionEvents([QueueTrigger(WebJobStorageQueueNames.AuctionEvents)] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Although this works, I would say that the best way is probably to have separate storage accounts for separate environments. Using different accounts, would allow you to keep the same queue names, but differentiate using you storage account connection strings - which is a much cleaner way.

Comment: agreed, but there is an added cost that comes with additional storage accounts, but there is also added cost in the time I spent trying to invent a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve queue names dynamically by implementing INameResolver.

Here's an example. The queue name resolver

```
public class QueueNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        //The name comes from the function in the WebJob
        if (name == "queueKey")
        {
            return "yourqueuename";
        }
        if (name == "queueKeyPoison")
        {
            return "yourqueuename-poison";
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

You need to specify the name resolver while configuring the webjob:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config =
            new JobHostConfiguration("your connection string")
            {
                NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver()
            };
        var host = new JobHost(config);

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
    public static void NewBidsQueue([QueueTrigger(%queueKey%)] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

The resolver receives the parameter "queueKey" and you can decide what queue name should be used depending on that.

There's more information [here.](http://bypassion.dk/?p=553)

Hope this helps,

Comment: I dont fully get it upon first read, but I'll give it a try.  thanks for the insight